# Sorting a series of Tickets

Tags: javascript

This is the problem statement,

You've a bunch of tickets in a stack with departures and destinations. You're given a departure city and a destination city. How can you find from the stack your route. 
This is my solution,

```
"use strict";


function app(){

    var stack = [];
    var one = new Ticket('London', 'NYC');
    var two = new Ticket('Barcelona', 'Athens');
    var three = new Ticket('Rio', 'ND');
    var four = new Ticket('NYC', 'Barcelona');
    var five = new Ticket('Athens', 'Rio');
    var six = new Ticket('ND', "Lahore");
    stack.push(one);
    stack.push(two);
    stack.push(three);
    stack.push(four);
    stack.push(five);
    stack.push(six);

    var res = sortDestinations(stack, 'London', 'Lahore');
    for(var city in res){
        console.out(res[city]);
    }

}
function Ticket(departure, destination){

    this.departure = departure;
    this.destination = destination;
}

Ticket.prototype.getDeparture = function(){
    return this.departure;
}

Ticket.prototype.getDestination = function(){
    return this.destination;
}


function sortDestinations(stack, dep, dest){
    var map = {};
    for(var i= 0; i<stack.length; i++){
        var ticket = stack.pop();
        map[ticket.getDeparture()] = ticket.getDestination();
    }
    var res = [];
    var curr = dep;
    res.push(curr);

    while(true){
        if(curr == dest) {
            break;
        }
        var next = map[curr];
        res.push(next);
        curr = next;
    }

}

app();
```

This program goes into an infinite loop. When I debug I see that the curr variable is undefined. Can someone help me solve the problem. I'm rank new to Javascript.

Comment: One problem I see is in `sortDestinations` you are calling `.pop()` (which modifies your stack) and your loop isn't doing what I think you are expecting it to.

Comment: For an arbitrary set of tickets, there could be no solution or many solutions.  The shortest solution (by ticket count or geographic distance) is NP-hard.  How much of that do you hope to take into account?

Comment: @danh the problem expects a solution to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was debugging your code for a while and finally identified the reason for `infinite loop`.
Since you are `pop`-ing from `stack`, length of `stack` keep decreasing and that of `i` increasing and the loop stops before completion. And your `while` loop keep looping since `curr` is never going to equal to `dept` because `map` does not contain `London`.

Change this

```
for(var i= 0; i<stack.length; i++){
    var ticket = stack.pop();
    map[ticket.getDeparture()] = ticket.getDestination();
}
```

To

```
while(stack.length>0){
    var ticket = stack.pop();
    map[ticket.getDeparture()] = ticket.getDestination();
}
```

Comment: I fixed that, but now it doesn't yield an output. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: How do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Apologies fixed, added a return statement to the function.