# Find a path among pairs of items based on their intersection

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list

What is the most efficient way (preferably in python-3.5+) to find the find a path among pairs of items based on following conditions:

> For two given pairs (s1, e1) and (s2, e2) they should be connected if either `e1 == s2` or `e2 == s1`. There are no duplicate paths here and each pair is contain two different names. Also, each pair can connects to only one other path and there is no isolated pair here, i.e. all of them can be connected.

For example if the input is:

```
[('Bergerac','Pau'),
('Nice','Montpelier'),
('Pau','Paris'),
('Marseille','Nice'),
('Montpelier','Bergerac'),
('new','Marseille'),
('old','new'),
('Paris', 'last'),
('dsd', 'sds')]
```

The output should be as following:

```
('old', 'new', 'Marseille', 'Nice', 'Montpelier', 'Bergerac', 'Pau', 'Paris', 'last')
```

P.S. This is a simple question but I couldn't find any duplicate so please leave the link in comments if you found one so that I can close/delete the question.

Comment: This is a common interview problem and has been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797507, although the full solution isn't explicitly written out.

Comment: @pkpnd: That's closely related; the problem at hand has more restrictions, and doesn't need such an involved algorithm.

Comment: @pkpnd That link doesn't provide a solution for this problem. Also it's not even Python.

Comment: @Kasramvd I know. I didn't claim it was an exact duplicate. It's just related so I thought you'd be interested, since it's close to what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple linear directed-graph problem.

Make a set from all the `s` elements, another from all the `e` elements.  Your starting location `here` is the one element in `here = s_set - e_set`.

Find the edge `path` with `here` as its first element.  Now, simply traverse the edge: `here = edge[1]`.  As you've already done in your answer, you can `pop` that edge from the available list, as this should speed up successive searches.  Repeat this paragraph until you have no more edges to traverse.

Comment: The `here = s_set - e_set` trick is good but In my answer you don't have to separate start and ends and even find the start. I understand the graph-based nature of the problem but the point here is that what we have is a list is actually an already created list and I was curious to see other solutions that deal with this problem at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make a dictionary and follow the key -> value chain. The trick is figuring out where to start, but you can do that by finding keys that don't have corresponding values. For instance:

```
def find(arr):
    d = {k: v for [k, v] in arr}
    paths = []
    for head in d.keys() - d.values():
        res = []
        while head in d:
            res.append(head)
            head = d[head]
        if len(res) > 2:
            paths.append(res) 
    return paths

%timeit find(arr)
#> 3.95 µs ± 30.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

It's possible you'll have more than one chain, so the above finds them all and filters out the that don't go anywhere (the `dsd`, `sds` pair in your data).

Comment: In Python-3 dictionary attributes are set-like object and support most of `set`'s functionalities. So just use `d.keys() - d.values()`.

Comment: That's a nice thing to know, thanks @Kasramvd. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Good  solution but it seems too messy and I think you can make it more concise. Also, given that you're using multiple iterations and all other changes I'm not sure why this performs faster than my answer. Maybe it's mostly because of the copying and those pops.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a container and update it while iterating over the names the each time it meets the conditions.

```
def find_path(names):
    names = names[:]
    total = names.pop()
    while names:
        (c1,*rest, e1)  = total
        for j, (c2,*rest2, e2) in enumerate(names):
            if c1 == e2:
                total = (c2, *rest2, e2, *rest, e1)
                names.pop(j)
            elif e1 == c2:
                total = (c1, *rest, e1, *rest2, e2)
                names.pop(j)
    return total
```

Demo and benchmark:

```
In [84]: find_path(lst)
Out[84]: 
('old',
 'new',
 'Marseille',
 'Nice',
 'Montpelier',
 'Bergerac',
 'Pau',
 'Paris',
 'last')

In [85]: %timeit find_path(lst)
12.9 µs ± 99.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: In your for loop it's possible that neither the `if` nor `elif` are true. In this case the `while` loop runs forever because `names` never gets `pop()`ed. This happens with the given array because the first test is with `('dsd', 'sds')`